# Electron-renderer does not load webpack bundle from file nor from webpack-dev-server

Tags: typescript, webpack, electron, webpack-dev-server

1. Electron-renderer does not load the html file including the script after I bundled it with webpack (dist folder).
   Image: [nothing loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4T0H.jpg)
   I am sure that I load the right file, because it gets loaded if I remove the script tag placed by html-webpack-plugin in the compiled 'index.html'.

I tried the same with the webpack-dev-server and the results are different depending on the setup.

1. I run webpack-dev-server first and after it started I start electron from another bash instance (a new GIT bash window or cmd window). The result is always an empty window like in the previous image [nothing loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4T0H.jpg).
2. If I run webpack-dev-server and electron from the same bash instance like so:

package.json

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "./start.sh"
  }
}
```

start.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

trap 'kill $(jobs -p)' EXIT
npm run serve &
npm run start:electron:server &
wait
```

There are two results (this could be due to the fact I dont add any timeout).

2.1 The DOM is not populated - like in the first image [nothing loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4T0H.jpg). But the bundled script is loaded [script loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60cxR.jpg).

2.2 The DOM is populated [DOM loaded](https://imgur.com/vqxKBFO) and the bundled script is laoded [script loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60cxR.jpg).
One can think that it works fine. But electron does reload empty sources if I change code [empty html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmL4m.jpg) [empty js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXPQr.jpg). Electron also does not show properties if I log an object and press the triangle on the left. [doesnt update log](https://imgur.com/xm5yRg7)

For every setup where I use webpack-dev-server (both same bash instance and different instances) I cannot close electron via the red cross on the top right nor via File | Exit after the webpack-dev-server started and electron listens to it. I suspect this is due to an open websocket [open websocket](https://imgur.com/oUSrrxC)

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "dist",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "target": "es2018",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "paths": {
            "engine": ["../engine"]
        }
    },
    "exclude": [
            "node_modules",
            "**/*.spec.ts"
    ]
}
```

webpack.renderer.common.js

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
  entry: './index.ts',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
    alias: {
      engine: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'engine')
    }
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'index.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'
  },
  target: 'electron-renderer',
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'index.html')
    })
  ]
};
```

webpack.renderer.dev.js

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const common = require('./webpack.renderer.common.js');

module.exports = merge(common, {
    mode: 'development',
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        port: 8000
    }
});
```

package.json

```
{
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start:electron": "cross-env electron .",
    "start": "./start.sh",
    "start:electron:server": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development electron .",
    "serve": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack.renderer.dev.js",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.renderer.dev.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "electron": "4.1.4",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "ts-loader": "^5.3.3",
    "typescript": "^3.4.4",
    "webpack": "^4.30.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.3.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.2.1",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^1.7.2"
  }
}
```

Electron should load from both the file and the server. It does neither of those and I think that the problem lies at webpack and the configs. I cant tell why electron can load the code either fully (DOM and script) or partially (just the script) on the initial request to the webpack-dev-server and than fails on any subsequent reload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've set up my project anew. And it does work now. I still don't know what went wrong, though.